# How can I install packages without starting their associated services?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, package-management

As you're probably aware, by default when you install a package on a Debian or Ubuntu based system, if the package contains a service, that service will generally be enabled and started automatically when you install the package.

This is a problem for me.

I've found myself needing to manage templates for building LXC containers. There are several containers, each corresponding to a Debian or Ubuntu release. (There are also Red Hat-based containers, but they aren't relevant here.)

```
/var/lib/libvirt/filesystems/debian6_template
/var/lib/libvirt/filesystems/debian7_template
/var/lib/libvirt/filesystems/ubuntu1004_template
/var/lib/libvirt/filesystems/ubuntu1204_template
```

Occasionally I will find that the templates have a missing package or need some other change, so I will chroot into them to install the package. Unfortunately when I do that, I wind up with several copies of the package's service running!

By way of example, I found the templates didn't have a syslog daemon, so I installed one:

```
for template in /var/lib/libvirt/filesystems/{debian,ubuntu}*_template; do
    chroot $template apt-get install rsyslog
done
```

And promptly wound up with four copies of rsyslog running. Not to mention two copies of exim4. Oops!

---

I read somewhere (though I can't find it again now) that it's not supposed to start services when running in a chroot, but that clearly isn't happening here.

One potentially viable [nasty hack](https://askubuntu.com/a/77530/75668) calls for temporarily replacing the various commands which actually start services, such as `start-stop-daemon` and `initctl`, though this is a lot more work than I really wanted to do. If I have no other choice, though...

The ideal solution here would be for Debian-based systems to stop doing this crap, but failing that, perhaps an obscure or undocumented command line option for `apt-get`?

In case it wasn't clear, I really want to keep anything related to managing the templates *outside* the templates, if possible.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For debian you can do this with [policy-rc.d](http://people.debian.org/%7Ehmh/invokerc.d-policyrc.d-specification.txt). Here's [one explanation](http://blog.zugschlus.de/archives/974-Debians-Policy-rc.d-infrastructure-explained.html):

> A package’s maintainer scripts are supposed to only interface with the init system by means of invoke-rc.d, update-rc.d and the LSB init script headers...
> invoke-rc.d will, before taking its action, check whether
> /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d is executable, will call it with the respective
> service name and the current runlevel number on its command line and
> act according to its exit code. For example, a return value of 101
> will prevent the planned action from being taken. This includes the
> automated start of the service upon package installation as well as
> the stop of the service on package removal and reduces the
> stop-upgrade-restart ritual during package upgrades to just performing
> the upgrade which might leave the old version of the service running

Since you don't want any services to ever start, your policy-rc.d script can be simply

```
#!/bin/sh
exit 101
```

This is the technique used by tools like pbuilder and Docker's [mkimage/debootstrap](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/72c21a7e5d8da44b39fc95b84efc2dbc5038f938/contrib/mkimage/debootstrap#L65).

Unfortunately, this technique [does not work with Ubuntu](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=571054) chroots. Packages that integrate with the upstart init system call /usr/sbin/initctl instead of invoke-rc.d during installation, and initctl doesn't consult policy-rc.d. [According to upstart's author](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/430224/comments/2) the workaround is to replace  /sbin/initctl with a symlink to /bin/true in a chroot. You can see this in mkimage-debootstrap as well, they do

```
dpkg-divert --local --rename --add /sbin/initctl
ln -sf /bin/true sbin/initctl
```

Comment: This seems pretty clean, though it also will have to be removed before creating a container from the template.

Comment: Thanks for this. I may end up just having to rip off Docker's mkimage-debootstrap script, as they seem to have mostly solved this problem.

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```
export RUNLEVEL=1
for template in /var/lib/libvirt/filesystems/{debian,ubuntu}*_template; do
    chroot $template apt-get install rsyslog
done
exit
```

I haven't tested it with chroot, but it should work.
At first it sets RUNLEVEL environment variable, so processes initiated by apt-get **will not start** any services, because they will "think" system is running in single mode. As environment is modified the way it may affect future commands, it is required to exit shell when modified environment is no longer needed, this is accomplished by *exit* command at the end.
There **may be** some (rare?) packages that won't install properly in single mode (but AFAIK this should not be problem in most cases).

Comment: Is `export RUNLEVEL=1` the important part here? What exactly does it cause to happen?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I believe the RUNLEVEL environmental variable will provide the current run level. In this instance he's just overwriting it so any application will think it's running on 1. It's sort of "kludge" but should suffice.

Comment: Added explanation to original answer. Basically this is what @WinkyWolly said.

Comment: Unfortunately `rsyslog` happened to be one of the "rare" packages which blew up completely when trying to install this way. This may still be useful, though, so you can keep the upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

Now that Debian (and Ubuntu) uses Systemd as its init system, a clean way to disable units before their installation is by using the [preset feature of Systemd](https://manpages.debian.org/stable/systemd/systemd.preset.5.en.html). This use case is even explained in the [Examples section](https://manpages.debian.org/stable/systemd/systemd.preset.5.en.html#EXAMPLES):

> ##### Example 1. Default to off
>
> ```
> # /lib/systemd/system-preset/99-default.preset
> disable *
> ```
>
> This disables all units. Due to the filename prefix "99-", it will be read last and hence can easily be overridden by spin or administrator preset policy.