# How to 'apt-get upgrade' a debootstraped chroot jail from outside?

Tags: debian, apt, chroot, debootstrap

I have a daemon running in a chroot jail that I have generated with debootstrap.

I'd like to remove apt and dpkg from the jail, but I want to keep the other packages updated.

Can I upgrade the packages in the jail, running apt-get from outside?

Comment: Related: [How can I install packages without starting their associated services?](http://serverfault.com/q/567474/126632)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you want to do this.  dpkg and apt are fundamental parts of a Debian system, and your chroot won't function independently without them.  Running

```
chroot /path/to/chroot apt-get update
```

and so on is a supported method that doesn't require removing dpkg and apt.

But if you're sure you want to do it, you can run

```
APT_CONFIG=/path/to/apt.conf apt-get update
```

where /path/to/apt.conf is the path of an apt.conf file that includes

```
RootDir /path/to/chroot;
```

The rest of the apt configuration will then be read from /path/to/chroot/etc/apt/apt.conf.d, or somewhere else under /path/to/chroot if you change `Dir::Etc` in the apt.conf file.  See the Description and Directories sections of `man apt.conf` for details.

Comment: I don't trust the daemon, and I want to harden the chroot a bit. I have already changed permissions in the chroot to avoid the user running the daemon can mknod, mount and so on... 
I want to remove apt and dpkg just because that they are not needed by the daemon to run: IMHO minimalism is a powerful security tool!

Comment: Reading the man page again, I'm not sure if this will cause the packages to install into the chroot.  Have you tried it, and did it work?

Comment: Didn't tried yet. But I've found a [debian bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=659387) related to this option. However defining "DPkg::Run-Directory" as "/" should be a viable workaround to that (still unfixed!) bug.
As a last resort, I could use `dpkg --root=/chroot -i package.deb`